Heat pump failed to work in aux/emergency mode?
I am selling my house, and the buyers just had the inspection performed. The inspection report showed that “the heat pump failed to work in auxiliary/emergency mode” and needs to be repaired. Can someone explain this to me better and give a ballpark estimate of what a repair like this would cost? A little surprised by this, as we just bought this house two years ago, and none of this was an issue.

explain this to me better .. what is your understanding of the problem?

We don't do cost estimates here, and the description depends on your hardware. Please see the [help] and take the [tour] so you know how to use this site.

It could be just the breaker needs rest

Typically, but there are variations, "aux" or "emergency" mode for a heat pump means not using the heat pump but instead depending on some other heat source when:

The heat pump isn't working properly
Outside temperature is below some particular point where it is expected that the heat pump won't work properly based on design

If you have a modern heat pump in a relatively warm area, it is quite possible you have never actually needed the emergency heat. If that's the case then:

It might never have worked properly
It might be broken (used to work properly)
It might not be configured/connected properly - which could be a heat pump problem or a thermostat problem

In addition, while emergency heat is often electric resistance heat (a.k.a., "toaster"), it may actually use an older gas furnace or something else. So it is impossible to guess what is wrong or how much it would cost to fix it. It could be anything from $100 for a service call to find/fix some loose or misconfigured wires on up to thousands of dollars for a furnace replacement.
With sufficient pictures of equipment, model #s, etc. it might be possible for random people on the internet to give you a better idea. But realistically, you should probably have a local trusted HVAC company take a look. Then you can either fix it (if it is small), give the buyer a credit towards repairs or get a second opinion. If the cost quoted to repair seems high then you can provide lots of details here ("what is involved in replacing the retro-encabulator on a model xyz...?") and we may be able to help.

The other reason to have a local pro look at it is that the buyer's inspector may be wrong. Mine was confused by my shower, which has an unusual dual handle setup where one is mix and the other is volume rather than hot/cold or a single-handle/combined setup. My seller corrected him/me on that; you can correct your buyer if their inspector really got it wrong.
